# Unable To Cycle Backwards Through Android Notifications

Tags: java, android, string, notifications, android-notifications

I have a series of notifications which appear two at a time to display a series of a total of 6-10 instructions (depending on the results of a web service call.) This portion of the code is working fine. The problem is when clicking BACKWARDS through the notifications cycle (if you click any of the two displayed notifications it will display the previous two notifications) it gets hungup at step 5 and does not display the 5th notifications and I'm having a bit of trouble determining why.

SCREENSHOT:

http://datasettings.site90.net/Screenshot_2013-10-03-11-37-20.png

SPECIFIC SOURCE:

```
private void setNotificationStrings(Bundle extras) {
    TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    // The code below sets the values of the current (field and value),
    // previous, and beforePrevious
    // Those hold the strings to display in the 2 notifications and the
    // strings to go back to
    // if the user decides to back track
    if (i == count) {
        done = true;
    }
    if (extras != null) {
         if (((tm.getSimOperator()).equals(getString(R.string.numeric_tmo)))) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Extras not null");
            previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.config_name_label));
            value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.apn_label));
            if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
                previousField = getString(R.string.config_name_label);
                previousValue = valuez.getAsString("name");
                Log.w("previousValue", previousValue);
                beforePreviousField = "step1";
                beforePreviousValue = "> New APN";
                //
                field = getString(R.string.apn_label);
                value = valuez.getAsString("apn");
                extras.clear();
                currentStep = 2;
                if (i == 1) {
                    j++;
                }
                Log.d("currentStep = ", " 2");
            } else {
                previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.apn_label));
        if (proxyArr.size() > 0)// if proxy and port are not null
            value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.proxy_label));
        else {
            value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mmsc_label));
            }
        if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
            previousField = getString(R.string.apn_label);
            beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.config_name_label);
                beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("name");
            if (proxyArr.size() > 0) {
                field = getString(R.string.proxy_label);
            value = valuez.getAsString("proxy");
                } else {
                field = getString(R.string.mmsc_label);
                    value = valuez.getAsString("mmsc");
            }
            extras.clear();
            currentStep = 3;
            Log.d("currentStep = ", " 3");
            } else {
                if (proxyArr.size() > 0) {// if proxy and port are not
                                            // null
                previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.apn_label));
                        value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.port_label));
                        if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
                previousField = getString(R.string.apn_label);
                beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.config_name_label);
                beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("name");
                            field = getString(R.string.port_label);
                value = valuez.getAsString("port");
                extras.clear();
                currentStep = 4;
                Log.d("currentStep = ", " 4");
                        } else {
                            previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.port_label));
                            value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mmsc_label));
                            if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
                    previousField = getString(R.string.port_label);
                    beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.proxy_label);
                    beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("proxy");
                                field = getString(R.string.mmsc_label);
                    value = valuez.getAsString("mmsc");
                    extras.clear();
                    currentStep = 5;
                    Log.d("currentStep = ", " 5");
                } else {
                                previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.port_label));
                if (mmsproxyArr.size() > 0) {// if mmsproxy
                                // and
                                // mmsport
                                // are not
                                // null
                    value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mms_proxy_label));
                } else {
                    value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.type_label));
                            }
                            if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
                            previousField = getString(R.string.mmsc_label);
                                beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.port_label);
                                beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("port");
                                if (mmsproxyArr.size() > 0) {
                    field = getString(R.string.mms_proxy_label);
                    value = valuez.getAsString("mmsproxy");
                    } else {
                    field = getString(R.string.type_label);
                    value = getString(R.string.type);
                    }
                    extras.clear();
                                currentStep = 6;
                    if (i < nameArr.size() - 1 && currentStep == 6) {
                        i++;
                    Log.d("currentStep = ", " 6");
                    } else {
                    if (mmsproxyArr.size() > 0) {// if
                                    // mmsproxy
                                    // and
                                    // mmsport
                                    // are
                                    // not
                                    // null
                        previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mms_proxy_label));
                                        value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mms_port_label));
                                        if (previousValue != null && value == null) {
                        previousField = getString(R.string.mms_proxy_label);        
                                            beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.mmsc_label);       
                                            beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("mmsc");   
                                            field = getString(R.string.mms_port_label);                                         
                                            value = valuez.getAsString("mmsport");                                      
                                            extras.clear();                                                 
                                            currentStep = 7;                                        
                                            Log.d("currentStep = ", " 7");
                                        } else {                                            
                                            previousValue = extras.getString(getString(R.string.mms_port_label));           
                                            value = extras.getString(getString(R.string.type_label));                   
                                            if (previousValue != null && value == null) {                                               
                                                previousField = getString(R.string.mms_port_label);                                     
                                                beforePreviousField = getString(R.string.mms_proxy_label);                                                      
                                                beforePreviousValue = valuez.getAsString("mmsproxy");                       
                                                field = getString(R.string.type_label);                                                     
                                                value = getString(R.string.type);                                                       
                                                extras.clear();                                                 
                                                currentStep = 8;                                                    
                                                Log.d("currentStep = "," 8");
```

FULL SOURCE:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1EjAo4bpnEjj6jExt7RY28EiA-fZIa1ExMBOfxzdGc3I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to SO, user2843378.

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on this?